# Typescript: duplicate function implementation message

Tags: typescript

I've created these two static factory methods into my class:

```
export class ConstantImpl<T> {
    public static create(b: Boolean): Constant<Boolean> {
        return new ConstantImpl<Boolean>(b);
    }

    public static create(i: Number): Constant<Number> {
        return new ConstantImpl<Number>(i);
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this compilation error message:

> Duplicate function implementation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do that kind of stuff in typescript, solution could be to have a create(a: any): Constant<any> then chec the type and call a specific function

Comment: They have the same name. For that you can use overloads. See the Overloads section: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: @CharybdeBE could you provide me some example is an answer?

Comment: The `Boolean` and `Number` types refer to objects created like `new Boolean(true)` or `new Number(5)`, not to the primitive `boolean` and `number` values like `true` and `5`.  If it is not really your intention to deal with such unusual non-primitives, you should change to `boolean` and `number` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cartant suggested, you can use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) in TypeScript.  They have a single implementation but multiple signatures.  You can read about it in the handbook to see how to make the signatures and implementation play well together.  In your case, you can do something like this:

```
export class ConstantImpl<T> {
  // guessing at your constructor
  public constructor(public val: T) {

  }

  public static create(b: boolean): Constant<boolean>;
  public static create(i: number): Constant<number>;
  public static create(v: boolean | number): Constant<boolean | number> {
        return new ConstantImpl(v);
    }
}
```

This will only allow `ConstantImpl.create()` to accept a `boolean` or a `number` value, and it will reject everything else.  Note that I didn't have to inspect the type of `v` to see if it is a `boolean` or a `number`, nor did I have to manually specify the value of `T` in the call to the `ConstantImpl<T>` constructor, because the constructor *infers* the value of `T` from the argument you pass in.

And really, in that case, it makes me wonder why you care to restrict `ConstantImpl.create()` to only accept `boolean` and `number` values.  Why not go the full generic route instead?

```
  // accept any type
  public static create<T>(v: T): Constant<T> {
    return new ConstantImpl(v);
  }
```

Hope that helps; good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment overloading is not implemented in typescript as it is in JAVA for example

You can try something like that

```
export class ConstantImpl<T> {
    public static create(a: any): Constant<any> {
        if(typeof a == "Boolean")
           return ConstantImpl.createBoolean(a);
        if(typeof a == "Number")
           return ConstantImpl.createNumber(a);
    }
   public static createBoolean(b: Boolean): Constant<Boolean> {
    return new ConstantImpl<Boolean>(b);
   }

}
```

ps: I do not have tested/compiled this specific function it is just an example type can be present